# Usage of uppercase word instead of lower after dialogue

Tags: grammar, spoken-english

**[SOURCE](https://books.google.com/books?id=NxNDDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA99)** (*Red Sister*, Mark Lawrence)

The following line appears in a novel I'm currently reading:

> "Go on!" Shouted from the platform, almost angry.

For speech tags I've often seen them lowercase like

> "Run!" he said.

For the latter one I believe because *said* is a transitive verb, it requires an object, namely the dialogue. I would think it's the same for *shouted* since it should also be a transitive verb and I have seen it used like *"Go," she shouted.* or something of the sort.

I have my doubts that it's a mistake, so I'm trying to understand why it's capitalized. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not a mistake. This is fiction, not a textbook. Mark Lawrence chose to write it this way because he liked the way it looked or sounded. He capitalized "Shouted" because he felt like it! That's all. There is no grammatical usage involved, and it can't be analyzed from a grammatical standpoint. "Angry" is an adjective, too, and not an adverb, and that's not a mistake, either.

Comment: @P.E.Dant That's true indeed, and I'm not doubting his usage, but I'm just trying to understand the differences, if any really, between using the lowercase and uppercase. Does the uppercase make the dialogue appear louder, or perhaps something else? Just slightly curious at the reason.

Comment: Ah, I see! Well, who knows? That makes this a "LitCrit" question, and supposedly off-topic here (although some get away with it from time to time.) He might have been trying to emphasize the angry shouting, I suppose, but to me, it looks as if he's just trying to be "different", and in comparison to _Finnegan's Wake_, it's pretty tame stuff.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a matter of orthography, not specifically about English language.

Comment: Actually it might not be arbitrary. The fragment may be understood as deleting certain conventional elements of syntax. The second sentence might be better understood if these were added back: "'Go on!' [The words were] shouted from the platform, almost angry." The audience for the deed is being characterized in that sentence. Now, it certainly could be the case that this passage is poorly written, but I was trained always to assume that an author is at least as intelligent as I am until proven otherwise, so I tend to give people the benefit of the doubt first.

Comment: So it's not LitCrit at all. Well finessed, @Robusto. Now we only have to figure out how that adjectival phrase migrated from its expected prenomial position to the end of the sentence. I pity the professor who assigned _you_ to read _Finnegan's Wake_! :)

Comment: @user178049 Hey! Stop trying to out-doctrinaire me. And what happened to the definite article before _English language_? Huh? :)

Comment: @P.E.Dant: I've tried to read *Finnegans Wake* (n.b. no apostrophe, in keeping with the punniness of the title) before, and though I like Joyce and have read everything else he wrote, I have to take that one a teaspoon at a time. ^_^

Comment: @Robusto I pray the good Finnegans forgive my apostrophal exhalation & go all back to their rest. I take a pint at a time meself! (But it's a challenge and you're right, it might as well have been written by a completely different fellow than the one who wrote short stories that are as intricate and perfect as a Swiss watch.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant My fingers were typing so quickly that the article can't even catch up with them. :)

Comment: @Robusto Read it aloud, preferably with an Irish accent, and it will move along mit grossem Schwung.

Comment: @StoneyB ...and a drop to fire the tongue, as he Drink a sip, drankasup...

Comment: @StoneyB: Indeed, it is music. *We pass through grass behush the bush to. Whish! A gull. Gulls. Far calls. Coming, far! End here. Us then. Finn, again!* I've often thought Joyce played with words and language the way Stravinsky played with tonalities. Why not bind them at their nexus points and drive a wedge through them even as they come together?

Comment: @Robusto Ah, a Burkean! ... "what we want is *not terms that avoid ambiguity*, but *terms that clearly reveal the strategic spots at which ambiguities necessarily arise*."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "“Go on!” Shouted from the platform, almost angry.

*Shouted from the platform* here is not a “speech tag”. It is not even a part of the same sentence as the spoken utterance *Go on!*; that’s why it starts with a capital. It is a new utterance which describes the preceding utterance—a new “sentence” if you like, but not a full clause, only a participle phrase (although of course as Robusto says it may be expanded into a full clause).

<sub>**WARNING: The following LitCrit is performed by a professional writer and critic. Emulate it at your own peril.**</sub>

<sup>Note that this distinctly non-narrative line—it has the form of a scrap of dialogue with an accompanying stage direction—appears as a separate paragraph, embedded in several paragraphs of precise and dispassionate narrative. I suggest that the author casts it in this form to mark it as an interruption, an external intrusion into Nona's focus on mounting. She does not see or look back toward the speaker urging her onward: she is aware only of the words and the tone. I think the author expresses this admirably.</sup>

Comment: I believe the proper disclaimer is: _"The following literary criticism was performed by a trained professional on a closed course. Do not attempt this at home."_